# debug BackboneJS + RequireJS instance variables like Collections, Models, etc

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Once RequireJS has been added to the BackboneJS app, I cannot access the instance variables in the chrome console.

Here is the example :

Only BackboneJS: http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/

Open chrome console and enter keys(window) to find the instance variable used in various BackboneJS scripts as "app" :

```
// instance variable app is also found under window
keys(window)
["top", "window", "location", "external", "chrome", "Intl", "v8Intl", "document", "_gaq", "_gat", "gaGlobal", "$", "jQuery", "_", "Backbone", "Store", "app", "jQuery191046978461160324514", "ENTER_KEY", "css", "cssFile", "cssRule"]

// debug the app object with Collections, Models, Views, Routers, etc
app
Object {Todo: function, todos: child, TodoView: function, AppView: function, TodoRouter: child…}
AppView: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
Todo: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
TodoFilter: ""
TodoRouter: child
TodoView: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
todos: child
__proto__: Object
```

BackboneJS + RequireJS: http://todomvc.com/dependency-examples/backbone_require/

Open chrome console and enter keys(window) and try to find out the instance variable of BackboneJS similar to the previous example :

```
keys(window)
["top", "window", "location", "external", "chrome", "Intl", "v8Intl", "document", "_gaq", "requirejs", "require", "define", "_gat", "gaGlobal", "_", "$", "jQuery", "css", "cssFile", "cssRule", "Backbone", "Store", "jQuery191032673427602276206"]

// I cant debug the BackboneJS object when it is used with RequireJS
```

How can I access the same instance variable "app" in the BackboneJS application with RequireJS ?

Is there a way to access the Collections, Models, Views, Routers, etc of a Backbone application when RequireJS is used?

I am unable to figure this out since over a week, can anyone pls help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of Require is to keep stuff out of the global scope (well, maybe not the *whole* point, but it's a main focus).  If you want to use a Require-ed module, you have to bring it in via Require.

The syntax for this, **IF** you have already loaded the module in question, is:

```
var app = require('path/to/module');
```

You should be able to use that to access any Require-ed file from the debugger.

Comment: Cool Thanks!. Is there a way to find out a list of all the loaded modules in chrome? 
I am still unable to get the list of collections for the todo app. Could you pls give me an appropriate command for it? Thanks again!

Comment: There may be such a command (I'd try looking at the Require.js documentation), but if so I don't know it, because I've never needed it.  The list of loaded files is basically the list of files in your require tree.  In other words, if your `data-main` points to `foo.js`, then any file required by `foo`, and any file required by a file required by `foo`, and any ... well you get the idea; all of those files will be loaded as soon as `foo` has loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot machineghost!

Comment: I am unable to get the collection variable used for todo app. Can you pls help me out with the file to be used as a command?

Comment: I'd recommend starting a new question for that; Stack Overflow is really designed for a "1 real life question to 1 Stack Overflow post" ratio, and if you try to cram multiple questions in to a single post it doesn't work very well.

Comment: i agree with that, but the question also mentions about finding about the collections, models, etc of the todo app. You can check the question again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Backbone Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd?hl=en) extension for Chrome. It supports RequireJS.

Alternatively, temporarily move variables to the global scope within your script:

```
window.app = /* a variable you need access to */
```